Sliding text animation in CSS
I would like to create something similar to this: https://codepen.io/marklc44/pen/RKPdEV. But having 6 elements, and the animation should be played 3 times, then stopped at the last element, only using CSS.
The example below only elements with three elements.


h3>.centered-container span {
  animation: vertical 7.5s linear 3 forwards;
  -ms-animation: vertical 7.5s linear 3 forwards;
  -webkit-animation: vertical 7.5s linear 3 forwards;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

h3>.centered-container span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

h3>.centered-container span:nth-child(3) {
  animation: vertical 7.5s linear 5s forwards 3, vertical-last 20000.5s 20.5s 1;
}

@keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes vertical-last {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    top: 0px;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    top: 0px;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    top: 0px;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
<h3>This<br>
  <div class="centered-container"> is   <span>one</span>
    <span>two</span>
    <span>three</span>
  </div>
</h3>




FYI, you don't need vendor prefixes for animation or animation-delay.

Good start, but you haven't asked a question. You've just described your requirements. Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask something clear and specific.

This is quite difficult to do with just css. But it is possible... The easiest way is to duplicate the slides. I also used a generator that I once created myself.
So, here's how you can do it:


.centered-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: .25em;
}

.slider{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  flex: auto;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.slide:last-child {
  transform: none;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
  animation: slide1 10s ;
}
@keyframes slide1 {
  0% { transform: translateY(100%); }
  2.2222222222222223%, 8.88888888888889% { transform: translateX(0); }
  11.11111111111111%, 100% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
        
.slide:nth-child(2) {
  animation: slide2 10s ;
}
@keyframes slide2 {
  0%, 11.11111111111111% { transform: translateY(100%); }
  13.333333333333332%, 20% { transform: translateX(0); }
  22.22222222222222%, 100% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
        
.slide:nth-child(3) {
  animation: slide3 10s ;
}
@keyframes slide3 {
  0%, 22.22222222222222% { transform: translateY(100%); }
  24.444444444444443%, 31.111111111111107% { transform: translateX(0); }
  33.33333333333333%, 100% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
        
.slide:nth-child(4) {
  animation: slide4 10s ;
}
@keyframes slide4 {
  0%, 33.33333333333333% { transform: translateY(100%); }
  35.55555555555555%, 42.22222222222222% { transform: translateX(0); }
  44.44444444444444%, 100% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
        
.slide:nth-child(5) {
  animation: slide5 10s ;
}
@keyframes slide5 {
  0%, 44.44444444444444% { transform: translateY(100%); }
  46.666666666666664%, 53.333333333333336% { transform: translateX(0); }
  55.55555555555556%, 100% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
        
.slide:nth-child(6) {
  animation: slide6 10s ;
}
@keyframes slide6 {
  0%, 55.55555555555556% { transform: translateY(100%); }
  57.77777777777778%, 64.44444444444444% { transform: translateX(0); }
  66.66666666666667%, 100% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
        
.slide:nth-child(7) {
  animation: slide7 10s ;
}
@keyframes slide7 {
  0%, 66.66666666666667% { transform: translateY(100%); }
  68.8888888888889%, 75.55555555555556% { transform: translateX(0); }
  77.77777777777779%, 100% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
        
.slide:nth-child(8) {
  animation: slide8 10s ;
}
@keyframes slide8 {
  0%, 77.77777777777779% { transform: translateY(100%); }
  80.00000000000001%, 86.66666666666667% { transform: translateX(0); }
  88.8888888888889%, 100% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
        
.slide:nth-child(9) {
  animation: slide9 10s ;
}
@keyframes slide9 {
  0%, 88.8888888888889% { transform: translateY(100%); }
  91.11111111111113%, 97.77777777777779% { transform: translateX(0); }
  100.00000000000001%, 100% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
<h3 class="centered-container">
  This is
  <div class="slider">
    <span class="slide">one</span>
    <span class="slide">two</span>
    <span class="slide">three</span>
    <span class="slide">one</span>
    <span class="slide">two</span>
    <span class="slide">three</span>
    <span class="slide">one</span>
    <span class="slide">two</span>
    <span class="slide">three</span>
  </div>
</h3>



